# Access variables of another function using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

im new to AngularJS. I have this kind of program in Controller File.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicModal, $state, $http, $ionicLoading) {
    var loginid;// globally Defined
    $scope.ajaxLogin = function(){
    loginid = 1;
    }

    $scope.myInfo = function(){
    alert(loginid);
    }

})
```

but everytime i call `myInfo()` function Alert gives me : `undefined`

in my program `ajaxLogin()` will call first. then if only button clicked `myInfo()` will call and alert will be displayed. in Normal Javascript it  work fine. but not sure how to work with angularjs.

ex :

```
var globalvarialbe;
function function1()
{
  globalvarialbe=12;

}

function function2()
{
  var local = globalvarialbe;
}
```

Comment: Please show more of the file. does both of the functions are defined in the same scope ?

Comment: its big code. i added only important thing to get idea. ill update code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in another [Forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/state-go-with-parameter-passing-parameters/18035).

just need to use `$rootScope`

```
$rootScope.loginid=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason i was asking for more information Cade Lewis is because the way you had it should have worked perfectly fine.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicModal, $state, $http, $ionicLoading) {
    var loginid;// globally Defined
    $scope.ajaxLogin = function(){
        loginid = 1;
    }

    $scope.myInfo = function(){
       alert(loginid);
    }

});
```

you can see its working here :
http://plnkr.co/edit/tkpmS1vqsOjhUp8rA99Y?p=preview

However you are not supplicating the whole picture so its kind hard debugging you issue

Comment: Exactly. As long as he is invoking the functions in the correct order, it should work fine.

Comment: I got it. maybe something wrong with my code. i thought angularJS way is different. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this code and it works just fine:

Controller:

```
angular.module('vars').controller('varsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

 var loginid;// globally Defined
$scope.ajaxLogin = function(){
    loginid = 1;
};

$scope.myInfo = function(){
    alert(loginid);
};

$scope.ajaxLogin();


}]);
```

HTML view:

```
 <div ui-view ng-controller="varsController">
            <button ng-click="myInfo()">Click</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to attach the variable to $rootScope to make it globally available in AngularJS. This is how:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicModal, $state, $http, $ionicLoading) {
    // Make sure you **inject $rootScope** first
    $rootScope.loginid;

    $scope.ajaxLogin = function(){
        $rootScope.loginid = 1;
    }

    $scope.myInfo = function(){
        console.log($rootScope.loginid); //Also, use console logs for better Dev Experience
    }
})
```

[Click here](https://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/learn-how-to-use-scopes-properly-in-angularjs/) for more detailed documentation on **HOW** to use scopes and how **NOT** to.